# G Suite Essentials access (temporary?)

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I have signed up for G Suite essentials (the free 3 months) but have decided not to provide payment details and therefore have no access to admin.google.com.
I can seem to be able to perform some basic tasks like creating meetings and uploading to Drive. It even says I have unlimited storage.
This all seems great, but I suspect Google is going to deactivate this account soon due to no payment details being in their system.
I'm just wondering how long this access will last without inputting payment details and a company address.